# Mindsdb: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading final connect information'

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mindsdb

My code keeps giving me the following error when connecting to Mindsdb: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading final connect information':

```
import mysql.connector
import os


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host= "cloud.mindsdb.com",
    user= os.environ.get("Random") ,
    password= os.environ.get("Random"),
    port= "3306",
    database= "mindsdb"

)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT response from mindsdb.ganggang_model WHERE author_username = "mindsdb" AND text="Hi How are you?"''')

for x in cursor:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Can you please share more info about the model you have trained? What is the output of DESCRIBE mindsdb.ganggang_model?